# localStorage: Textarea showing "undefined" on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm using LocalStorage to remember the value of fields. I noticed however that when my optional textarea field is left blank it shows a message saying "undefined". Really it should just how the placeholder. Where is the undefined text coming from and how do I remedy this?

**Text Area**

```
<textarea name="note" id="note" form="order" placeholder="Add your note..."></textarea>
```

**loadStorage Functions**

```
function loadSettings() {
    $('#note').val(localStorage.setnote);
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.setnote = $('#note').val();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you would have the following code:

```
function loadSettings() {
    $('#note').val(localStorage.getItem("setnote") || defaultValue); // The "|| defaultValue" is probably what you're looking for
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.setItem("setnote", $('#note').val());
}
```

Replace `defaultValue` with the value you want to set if there is no `setnote` in the `localStorage` (for example, the first time the user would load the page, and no settings exist yet). This will prevent the function to return `undefined`.

Note that you can keep using `localStorage['setnote']` or `localStorage.setnote` to access the stored property; the only upside to using `getItem` and `setItem` instead is that you can use it store objects under names that would otherwise be reserved, such as `length`, `key`, `setItem`, `getItem`, `removeItem`, and `clear`.

The prototype to do such a thing are:

```
localStorage.setItem('nameOfMyValue', value);
```

You can then retrieve it using

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('nameOfMyValue');
```

Answer (score 3):

`undefined` is showing up because there is no property 'setnote' under the localstorage object.

try using this instead

```
function loadSettings() {
    $('#note').val(localStorage.setnote || '');
}
```

the `||` will use `null` if localStorage.setnote is undefined

if the value of `localStorage.setnote` is `0` than this will replace with ' '. To avoid that you could do the following:

```
function loadSettings() {
    if(localStorage.setnote != null && typeof localStorage.setnote != 'undefined') {
        $('#note').val(localStorage.setnote || '');
    }
}
```

Comment: What? `||` will use `''` if `Boolean(localStorage.setnote) === false`. So if your `setnote` contains `0` for example, you will not see it.

Comment: "contains" is not accurate, it would have to evaluate to false so yes if the value is exactly `0` it will use `' '`. Perhaps a good example where being lazy has its downsides.

Comment: and you can check `localStorage.setnote !== undefined` directly just like `null`

Answer (score 0):

localStorage.myItem[0] = " ";

That is my way to solve the problem.